# Protection Against File Inclusion Vulnerability in PHP

Tags: php, xss, include-path

So I read on [oWasp](https://www.owasp.org) that this piece of code `<?php include 'yourfile.php';?>` is pretty high on the risk level for file inclusion or code injection. What is the best protection against that vulnerability?  How do I block all requests coming outside of the app?

Now please, this is not a debate, just provide a solution, if you have one.

Comment: 1. Don't allow to create PHP files. 2. Don't allow user input to dictate what you include. 3. Never use `eval`. 4. Never trust user data. Sanitize them. 5. Don't trust data in your database(resource) that might have come from user input by some other channel.

Comment: @Sylwester: Yes but I've been looking everywhere for an example how to actually protect the include() without much success... Do you have a piece of code something I can see?

Comment: Where does the file and the included file come from and which file privileges are on those files? The PHP class loader does include so when no tainted include is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Sylwester: Well... Can you explain why I keep getting unwanted 302 redirects whenever I include this particular file : `include 'includes/head.php';`? I get redirected to `yourdomain.com`

Comment: In simple terms: `<?php include 'yourfile.php';?>` is fine. This is not: `<?php include $_POST['user_value'] . '.php';?>`. It only becomes vulnerable if user input has control over it. Be it through a form or some database value.

Comment: @Sylwester : See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1324057/unwanted-302-in-php-app) this is me but they closed my question saying it's not specific enough. I don't know how more specific I need to be. Scratching my head intensely. I've been having the problem for 2 weeks unable to solve it. So I've been documenting myself on all types of security issues reading everything online I could find to try to fix it. I'm lost.

Comment: That can be tons of different things and you have not provided ANY information. Start at access.log and error.log and perhaps the same logs for the particular virtualhost. Perhaps you'll find `yourdomain.com` there somewhere. Then I would look at the php script itself. If you do `header('Location: ...)` the location needs to be fully qualified. eg. `/login/` doesn't cut it. It doesn't seem like you have provided the info that is needed to sole the mystery.